# mqtt broker bridge (in windows machine)

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm working in mqtt broker bridge, I have to connect local mosquitto to remote mosquitto.

```
connection remote-mosquitto-bridge
address 10.1.0.9:1883
topic test both 1
```

Above code is added in mosquitto.conf file for connect remote machine(10.1.0.9 is my remote)

its enough for message sharing to local to remote

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Test the configuration you have presented and if it doesn't work include a full description of what you expect to happen and what actually happed and we'll help you fix it. But as it stands we don't have enough information to actually help with anything

Answer (score 0):

You need config the listener port
ex:
if your diagram is like that

```
broker 1 => broker 2
```

Broker 1 mosquitto.config:

```
connection remote-mosquitto-bridge
address 10.1.0.9:1883
topic # both 0
```

Broker 2 mosquitto.config:

```
port 1883
listener 8883
```

This work for me.

source:
https://medium.com/jungletronics/mosquitto-bridge-5b44e9687fb3